# Does not show output for all mutliple modules in an android project running the ./gradlew detekt

Tags: android, detekt

I am using detekt and have a android project that contains `presentation`, `domain`, and `data` modules.

When running `./gradlew detekt`
It only show the output for the data module.

However, when I run the following `./gradlew :domain:detekt` or `./gradlew :presentation:detekt`
It will show the output from those modules.

However, I want to be able to show the output for all modules when running this command `./gradlew detekt`

In my project level build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${libs.versions.version.kotlin.get()}")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:${libs.versions.version.google.dagger.get()}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:${libs.versions.version.kotlin.get()}")
        classpath("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.19.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.19.0"
}

apply(plugin = "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

I have added the plugin for the following modules:
Presentation:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
}
```

Domain:

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("kotlin")
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
}
```

Data

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
}
```

Here is the github repo for the project I am trying to configure for detekt
https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyFood/tree/develop-detekt

Answer (score 0):

Need to use continue

`./gradle detetk --contine`